# Dynamic summary formula

Tags: reporting, formula

I want to create a summary formula on a report that changes it's value based on the entered date from the filters.

Imagine this, a formula that multiplies a value with the number of days, like:
Value * X days. X days value is returned from the date filter interval.

I know that this probably is not supported but, anyone has some idea on how to get this to work dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

To show a report like this, you would need to have multiple date-based object records in your database to summarize up.

For example, you want to report on Revenue on a monthly basis, and want your report to show how much revenue you made over a span of 6 months.

- Create a custom object called `Revenue Entry` that has a date
  and a currency field on it, and looks up to Opportunity.
- Each Opportunity will have multiple Revenue Entries: one for each month
  it is generating revenue.
- The report in this case is over Revenue Entries, and is grouped at the Opportunity level. The date filter is the range you're looking for, and there will be 6 Revenue Entries per Opportunity if you Show Details, since there are 6 months in the date filters.

In this situation, you can use standard Salesforce reports to show the information you require, but you will probably want some kind of automation to create all those individual date-related records. Creation of these detail-type records could be accomplished with a trigger or scheduled batch process. If you need to report down to the day, you will need an individual record for every day. Obviously, this could cause an explosion in data storage, and may not be practical for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what I want. I want to be able to change the date filter of the report and the summary formula change accordingly

Comment: This is the only way I know of to do what you are asking. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You correctly identify that this not possible with standard report. You can Write a VF page that can give you this result. you can create wrapper class that process and find value using your formula and entered filter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the use of a VF page is not an option for this problem.

Comment: IMO this the only way.. there is no way that we can do it with standard report as standard report can not access  filter for manipulating the data. Filter are like conditions and can be use for selection of data but not as parameter for formula to manipulate the data.